# About the risk of missing events when attaching handlers in useEffect() callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am worried about attaching listeners in the `useEffect()` callback, some events can be missed.

[Take the example of the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#effect-hook):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FriendStatus(props) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  function handleStatusChange(status) {
    setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

Let's imagine the friend status change event is fired after the `FriendStatus` compontent
was instantiated but before the `useEffect` is invoked.
In this case for example:

```js
function App() {

  Promise.resolve().then(()=> ChatAPI.postFriendStatus({ "id": 42, "isOnline": true }));

  return (<FriendStatus firend={{ "id": 42 }}) />);


}
```

We then miss the event and `FriendStatus` stays 'Loading...' forever.

Any opinions on the matter much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a hot vs cold observables problem.

In order to make this work you should buffer some number of events (maybe only one) inside ChatAPI (Observable), for example, and replay buffered events for every new subscription.

See https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject as the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It comforts me into thinking I should care about this edge case.
However, I am looking for a solution on the react side.
If I don't find a better way I will mark your answer as accepted but for now I am still investigating.